# Given that 1D space $\mathbb{R}$ and 3D space $\mathbb{R}^3$ are in bijection, why do we describe our physical world as 3D?

Tags: spacetime, differential-geometry, topology, spacetime-dimensions

Mostly the reason given is that that three numbers are required to specify a point uniquely in our world. But this is utter nonsense!

It has long been mathematically proven that $\mathbb{R}$ is in bijection with $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e. $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ have the same [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality). So what is the “additional theoretical structure” (which has to be physical, not mathematical, since we’re describing our physical world) that prompts us to label our space as “3D”?

---

**Note:** I am not talking about including time as the fourth dimension. This is under the theory of relativity. And I am asking a more general question.

Comment: Re, "...proven...bijection..." Can you show an example? E.g., Can you show an equation to predict the motion of a planet orbiting a star in which you use a _single_ real variable to represent the planet's position in space, a single real variable to represent its momentum, etc.? The math for that looks pretty simple when you do it using 2D or 3D vectors, but I wonder what it would look like using only scalar variables and your bijection.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Just because something looks complicated, can we rule out its possibility? I ask for precise and sound reasons for why this is not possible.

Comment: In a word, "yes." If you want to rank scientific theories, the worst theories make predictions that are untrue, and the best theories make accurate predictions that other theories fail to do. But in-between those extremes, there is a realm where theories are ranked by _elegance_. If your theory and the other guy's theory make all the same predictions, and of neither of your theories makes any prediction that is untrue, but your theory is harder to work with than the other guy's; then the scientific community is going to accept the other guy's theory, and not yours.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly My question is physical.

Comment: @atom can you clarify why you think a bijection is enough so that 3- and 1-dimensional space are equivalent in any meaningful sense? A vector space is not just a set of numbers for points, but it has a certain algebraic and topological structure, why is this not relevant here, in your opinion?

Comment: @StephanMatthiesen I agree. But I’m asking for a *physical* theory which says reasons that space is 3d.

Answer (score 6):

The key is to view space(time) $M$ as a [differential manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold) with a differential structure rather than just a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)). One may show that two differential manifolds $M$ and $N$ can only be [diffeomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism) if they have the same dimension.

Comment: Interesting! So can I conclude that the agreement of observations with our physical theories which view the space as a 3D manifold, make us claim that the world is 3D?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with such bijections, also known as [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve), is that they are cumbersome to work with, and have some properties that make them useless for physical theories. For example, (square of) distance between two points in 3D Euclidean space is a smooth function:

$$d^2=\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2+\Delta z^2.$$

But in a space-filling curve this would be a discontinuous function of the two curve parameters corresponding to the two points. This then leads to impossibility of convenient description of trajectories, and this affects the whole of physics, starting already from kinematics.

Comment: Space filling curves are continuous in the forwards direction. It's only the backwards direction that fails.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}$ is in set-theoretic bijection with $\mathbb{R}^3$ but the two are not homeomorphic. That means that to a mathematician they are only 'the same' as sets, and not as topological spaces. In particular, any bijection between them *must be discontinuous in at least one direction*. For instance, space filling curves do not have continous inverses.

The topological structure of space is incredibly important. Physicists do a lot more than just talk about abstract sets, we have a notion of closeness that topology furnishes. Of course, many theories have *even more* structure than this. You might be able to actually measure the distance between points for instance! Regardless, we normally need some mathematical structure beyond set theory for the theory to make any physical sense. You might as well ask why we don't describe the universe as a circle, since they are also in bijection with $\mathbb{R}^3$ - the reason is that any structure that meaningfully makes it 'a circle' includes the (topological) fact that you can wrap around on yourself, which is not observed in our space.